# Permutations with exclusions - phone numbers problem

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

Problem from "Introduction to Probability" by Blitzstein-Hwang:

> a) How many 7-digit phone numbers are possible assuming phone numbers can't start with 0 or 1.

> b) Re-solve a) but now phone numbers can't start with 911 either.

The best I could come up with was:

a) **8 000 000** (8 x 10^6);

b) **5 670 000** (7 x 9^2 x 10^4);

Is this the right way of thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer for (a) is correct, but for (b), you just need to subtract the number of phone numbers starting with 911. Number of such phone numbers is $10^4$ because once you set the leftmost part to 911, you can choose the other fours digits arbitrarily.

Comment: Thank you, @gunes. I'd never have thought of that....